# Need to split up a quiz written in javascript into 1 page per Q instead of all Qs on a single page

Tags: javascript, scorm, scorm1.2

I have a quiz currently all on one page written in javascript. I need to rewrite/modify/split up this code so each question appears on its own page.

I used a tool called [eXeLearning](http://exelearning.net/?lang=en) to build the quiz. This is part of a SCORM project that will be hosted on an LMS. I'm just not sure how to go about this. I'm good with HTML and CSS and I know a little PHP, but not javascript. Here is the script in question, I can also post the entire page of code if need be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- //<![CDATA[
var numQuestions = 10;
var rawScore = 0;
var actualScore = 0;
var question0;
var question1;
var question2;
var question3;
var question4;
var question5;
var question6;
var question7;
var question8;
var question9;
var key0 = 0;
var key1 = 1;
var key2 = 0;
var key3 = 0;
var key4 = 1;
var key5 = 0;
var key6 = 0;
var key7 = 1;
var key8 = 0;
var key9 = 1;
function getAnswer()
    {
        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.0.id","key0b0");
        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.0.type","choice");
        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.0.correct_responses.0.pattern",
                      "0");

        for (var i=0; i < 2; i++)
        {
           if (document.getElementById("quizForm0").key0b0[i].checked)
           {
              question0 = document.getElementById("quizForm0").key0b0[i].value;
              scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.0.student_response",question0);
              break;
           }
        }

        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.1.id","key1b0");
        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.1.type","choice");
        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.1.correct_responses.0.pattern",
                      "1");

        for (var i=0; i < 2; i++)
        {
           if (document.getElementById("quizForm0").key1b0[i].checked)
           {
              question1 = document.getElementById("quizForm0").key1b0[i].value;
              scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.1.student_response",question1);
              break;
           }
        }

        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.2.id","key2b0");
        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.2.type","choice");
        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.2.correct_responses.0.pattern",
                      "0");

        for (var i=0; i < 2; i++)
        {
           if (document.getElementById("quizForm0").key2b0[i].checked)
           {
              question2 = document.getElementById("quizForm0").key2b0[i].value;
              scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.2.student_response",question2);
              break;
           }
        }

        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.3.id","key3b0");
        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.3.type","choice");
        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.3.correct_responses.0.pattern",
                      "0");

        for (var i=0; i < 2; i++)
        {
           if (document.getElementById("quizForm0").key3b0[i].checked)
           {
              question3 = document.getElementById("quizForm0").key3b0[i].value;
              scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.3.student_response",question3);
              break;
           }
        }

        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.4.id","key4b0");
        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.4.type","choice");
        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.4.correct_responses.0.pattern",
                      "1");

        for (var i=0; i < 2; i++)
        {
           if (document.getElementById("quizForm0").key4b0[i].checked)
           {
              question4 = document.getElementById("quizForm0").key4b0[i].value;
              scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.4.student_response",question4);
              break;
           }
        }

        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.5.id","key5b0");
        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.5.type","choice");
        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.5.correct_responses.0.pattern",
                      "0");

        for (var i=0; i < 2; i++)
        {
           if (document.getElementById("quizForm0").key5b0[i].checked)
           {
              question5 = document.getElementById("quizForm0").key5b0[i].value;
              scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.5.student_response",question5);
              break;
           }
        }

        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.6.id","key6b0");
        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.6.type","choice");
        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.6.correct_responses.0.pattern",
                      "0");

        for (var i=0; i < 2; i++)
        {
           if (document.getElementById("quizForm0").key6b0[i].checked)
           {
              question6 = document.getElementById("quizForm0").key6b0[i].value;
              scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.6.student_response",question6);
              break;
           }
        }

        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.7.id","key7b0");
        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.7.type","choice");
        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.7.correct_responses.0.pattern",
                      "1");

        for (var i=0; i < 2; i++)
        {
           if (document.getElementById("quizForm0").key7b0[i].checked)
           {
              question7 = document.getElementById("quizForm0").key7b0[i].value;
              scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.7.student_response",question7);
              break;
           }
        }

        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.8.id","key8b0");
        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.8.type","choice");
        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.8.correct_responses.0.pattern",
                      "0");

        for (var i=0; i < 2; i++)
        {
           if (document.getElementById("quizForm0").key8b0[i].checked)
           {
              question8 = document.getElementById("quizForm0").key8b0[i].value;
              scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.8.student_response",question8);
              break;
           }
        }

        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.9.id","key9b0");
        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.9.type","choice");
        scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.9.correct_responses.0.pattern",
                      "1");

        for (var i=0; i < 2; i++)
        {
           if (document.getElementById("quizForm0").key9b0[i].checked)
           {
              question9 = document.getElementById("quizForm0").key9b0[i].value;
              scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.9.student_response",question9);
              break;
           }
        }
       }
    function calcRawScore(){

        if (question0 == key0)
        {
           scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.0.result","correct");
           rawScore++;
        }
        else
        {
           scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.0.result","wrong");
        }
        if (question1 == key1)
        {
           scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.1.result","correct");
           rawScore++;
        }
        else
        {
           scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.1.result","wrong");
        }
        if (question2 == key2)
        {
           scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.2.result","correct");
           rawScore++;
        }
        else
        {
           scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.2.result","wrong");
        }
        if (question3 == key3)
        {
           scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.3.result","correct");
           rawScore++;
        }
        else
        {
           scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.3.result","wrong");
        }
        if (question4 == key4)
        {
           scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.4.result","correct");
           rawScore++;
        }
        else
        {
           scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.4.result","wrong");
        }
        if (question5 == key5)
        {
           scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.5.result","correct");
           rawScore++;
        }
        else
        {
           scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.5.result","wrong");
        }
        if (question6 == key6)
        {
           scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.6.result","correct");
           rawScore++;
        }
        else
        {
           scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.6.result","wrong");
        }
        if (question7 == key7)
        {
           scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.7.result","correct");
           rawScore++;
        }
        else
        {
           scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.7.result","wrong");
        }
        if (question8 == key8)
        {
           scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.8.result","correct");
           rawScore++;
        }
        else
        {
           scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.8.result","wrong");
        }
        if (question9 == key9)
        {
           scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.9.result","correct");
           rawScore++;
        }
        else
        {
           scorm.SetInteractionValue("cmi.interactions.9.result","wrong");
        }
    }

    function calcScore2()
    {
       computeTime();  // the student has stopped here.

       document.getElementById("quizForm0").submitB.disabled = true;

       getAnswer();

       calcRawScore();

       actualScore = Math.round(rawScore / numQuestions * 100);
    alert("Your score is " + actualScore + "%")  

       scorm.SetScoreRaw(actualScore+"" );
       scorm.SetScoreMax("100");

       var mode = scorm.GetMode();

           if ( mode != "review"  &&  mode != "browse" ){
             if ( actualScore < 80 )
             {
               scorm.SetCompletionStatus("incomplete");
               scorm.SetSuccessStatus("failed");
             }
             else
             {
               scorm.SetCompletionStatus("completed");
               scorm.SetSuccessStatus("passed");
             }

             scorm.SetExit("");
             }

     exitPageStatus = true;


     scorm.save();

     scorm.quit();

    }
//]]> -->
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question and you will certainly need to learn JavaScript (or hire somebody) in order to solve this. I also recommend learning JQuery especially if you go with option 1 below. There's lots of sites that will teach you.

In terms of the general approach you can take, you have two choices:

1. Keep everything on one page and show/hide quiz questions as the learner progresses through.
2. Put questions in frames and pass data back to the parent frame.

I'd use option 1 myself because frames are quite old fashioned now.

Pick an approach, take some time to learn JavaScript and JQuery and then come back with more specific questions about problems you run into implementing the approach you choose.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Andrew. I started to learn some jQuery a while back, obviously I need to pick that back up.

Comment: Agree with Andrew, except about frames being old-fashioned -- iframes are part of HTML5 spec and even have new features like sandboxing. :) But if your "course" is just a series of questions, you can definitely do in the style of a single page app. There are lots of approaches and tutorials out there (minus the SCORM code). For example this was top result in my Google search: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-spiffy-quiz-engine--net-20185